# File Explorer crashes when i select a file

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

Ok so i have tried EVERYTHING like EVERYTHING.
I searched ALOT to solve this problem and seems like nothing works.
I dont really wanna reinstall windows since i have did it recently and now this happened.
List of stuff i tried:

1. Clearing explorers histor
   y or something
2. deleting some reigstry keys (BagMBR and Bag somewhere idk)
3. Tweaking explorers settings until i did not know what i was doing
4. Updating windows for 4 hours
5. 2 Virus scans (None showed bad results)
6. reinstalling my graphics driver
7. Restarting explorer and my pc 7 times
8. Reinstalling java (for some reason dont ask)
9. Automatic repair
10. SFC /scannow and some DISM stuff
11. chkdsk
12. **Veryfying event log** (Nothing but malwarebytes services failed to load)
13. *i dont even know anymore dont ask ok*

So yea, alot of stuff. I really need help and yes file explorer only crashes when i select A FILE and it just works normally otherwise.
I can navigate trough folders and that stuff, otherwise windows works just fine.

Comment: Try [Windows Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html) (freeware version is sufficient). Do **everything** it says, don't skip bits.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that some of your attempted fixes, e.g. Registry changes,  have made the issue worse, preventing repair. If you have previously installed an alternative file browser, **completely uninstall it** before attempting any other fix. Search the Registry to see if there are remnants of the application.

If you do not want to download the [latest Windows 10 ISO image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) direct from Microsoft and to reinstall, choosing the option to keep your files (yes, this *is* time consuming, but no more so than making blind changes), then you might [try a third-party Windows Explorer replacement](https://techshaggy.com/windows-explorer-alternatives/), such as [XYPlorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/) or [FreeCommander](https://freecommander.com).

That said, the third-party alternatives I've used might lack some features of Windows Explorer.  For example, some do not show extended attributes, such as image dimensions or document author, though Explorer **can** display those columns.

So try an alternative file browser... most are free. Before installing any software, check it at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload), though.

Comment: I have installed a alternative file broswer, but it was OldNewExplorer and i uninstalled it tough. I asked myself now would oldnewexplorer fix this issue? Maybe... But not surely since it just adds some old features to explorer and it doesnt completely overwrtie explorer as i know. But i mean it is what it is, ill try the alternatives. Thanks.